# wpf Command Ctr + C cannot copy value from textbox when messagebox show up

Tags: wpf, messagebox

[image: enter image descenter image description here]

[image: ription here]

When the message box showing, although I have focused on the textbox I cannot Ctr + C value of the textbox, it always copies text from the message box,
However, Ctr + X still working

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. By my side the message box does block the execution in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the window you want to block into the message box as a first parameter.

For `MainWindow` you can use `Application.Current.MainWindow`.

```
MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, Message.GetMessage(messageId, msgArgs), messageId, button, messageIcon, defaultButton);
```

[MessageBox.Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox.show?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_MessageBox_Show_System_Windows_Window_System_String_System_String_System_Windows_MessageBoxButton_System_Windows_MessageBoxImage_System_Windows_MessageBoxResult_)